# RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "Firebase.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"kakashi"
                                               initialProperties:nil
                                                   launchOptions:launchOptions];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

@end
```

Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'my_app' do
  pod 'Firebase/Core'

end
```

Verified that `Build phase/Link Binary with Libraries` has libRNFirebase.a [image]

I've also verified the `$(inherited)` is there for framework search paths.

Still getting error `RNFirebase core module was not found natively on iOS` with `expo start` or `npm start`

Can you please recommend how to approach this problem? Or any help with what to verify/ensure for this to work is much appreciated.

Comment: how did you open the project in xcode  by .xcodeproject or xworkspace ? here you have to run pod install once you run that command my_app.xworkspace file will generate.

Comment: @OsmanGoniNahid yep, generated the .xcworkspace file already. Trying to run with npm start instead of xcode.
Also the mentioned settings are from the xcworkspace configs